# rope - knotted or does not knot

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, probability, topology

[image]

The figure shows the shadow of a piece of rope on the ground, and you can't see which part is on which part; Suppose the rope is placed completely randomly. Now tighten the two ends of the rope to the left and right. What is the probability that the rope will be tied into a knot?

Comment: Once again you've chosen tags that have no relevance to this puzzle.

Comment: so maybe only calculation puzzle and no computers?

Comment: i added the logical deduction tag. remove if not applicable, but i think i see the answer, and i arrived at it through logical deduction

Comment: I think there won't be an answer unless "completely randomly" is fully defined. In mathemacial terms, you need to specify your probability space, e.g. does every crossing has equal and independent probability of being over- or under-crossing.

Comment: @WhatsUp If "completely randomly" in this case *does not* mean "every crossing has equal and independent probability of being over- or under-crossing", then what else could it possibly mean?

Comment: @JLee A lot of possibilities. E.g. the rope could be interpreted as an eulerian path from one end to the other; or it could make turns at random on each vertex (thus a conditional probability); it could also be the trace  of a brownian movement on that "shadow", which in the end covers the whole shadow. I'm not saying what is probably the intended meaning, just saying that the question is not well defined.

Comment: Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Comment: If the rope is "*placed completely randomly*", it's almost certain that it *won't* be knotted. E.g. pick up the centre and drop it randomly, or hold the two ends and drop them randomly.  One would have to deliberately go out of their way to force the middle crossing to be different from the other two.

Comment: @JLee I agree with WhatsUp here. Sometimes we might need to specify it more clearly. A famous example where different kind of random might arise is [Bertrand's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)). There are many ways to mathematically interpret "choosing a chord in a circle randomly".

Comment: For a mathematics book, technicality is a must, but for a puzzle, when there is mild ambiguity, instead of nit-picking, go with the interpretation that is obviously meant (in your view). Think to yourself, what kind of puzzle would this be if the intended meaning was something else? It wouldn't be much of a puzzle at all, would it? So, go with the intended meaning and mention your assumptions in your answer. We will never reach a point where all puzzles posted will be rigorously technical, and if we did, then our audience would shrink 100 fold.

Comment: @bobble I read the definition of proper attribution, but the only thing I have is a image.

Comment: @JLee, I think everyone understood the intent, and the comments are mostly intended to encourage better wording in general.  E.g. replacing "*; Suppose the rope is placed completely randomly*" with something like "*and have no reason to think one way is more likely than the other*" would remove the ambiguity.

Comment: @RayButterworth Good points.

Comment: @MrMonkey where did you find the image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the rope is just a normal rope and the only unknowns are how does it intersect in the three points marked in red in the following picture (i.e. no strange topology, no funny direction changes at the intersections).

> [image: intersections]

There are only 8 possible dispositions, I colored the rope with two different colors (red and green) to show them.
I call the dispositions with a sequence of three R (red) or G (green), depending on which part of the rope is above in each of the three intersections.

> RRR
>  [image: RRR]
>  RRG
>  [image: RRG]
>  RGR
>  [image: RGR]
>  RGG
>  [image: RGG]
>  GRR
>  [image: GRR]
>  GRG
>  [image: GRG]
>  GGR
>  [image: GGR]
>  GGG
>  [image: GGG]

Assuming that by "completely random" OP means that on each overlapping point there is $1/2$ probability that the red part is above the green part and $1/2$ probability that the green part is above. This will result into a uniform distribution among the 8 possible combinations.

Only configurations RGR and GRG will be tied into a knot, so the requested probability is

> $2/8 = 1/4$

Proof that only these combinations will be tied into a knot:

> Well, I tried with a physical rope. Sorry I don't have a better proof.

Comment: @JLee no problem. I actually cheated a little bit by posting the text of the answer and adding the images and the "proof" later. I think you can post your answer too, looking at the timestamps most user will know that we were trying to solve this puzzle independently.

Comment: LOVE the proof!

Comment: Love it! Nice and obvious.

Answer (score 5):

The probability is

> 25%

The reason:

> There are three points where the ropes cross each other
> If we start from the left end, and look at that rope, the first three crossings have 8 possible configurations. If we denote "on top" as '1' and "underneath" as '0', these configurations are just like the binary numbers 0 (0b000) through 7 (0b000):
>  `0 0 0`
>  `0 0 1`
>  `0 1 0`
>  `0 1 1`
>  `1 0 0`
>  `1 0 1`
>  `1 1 0`
>  `1 1 1`
>
>  For the rope to end up in a knot, you need either `010` or `101` - two out of eight possible configurations.

Answer (score 3):

Probability:

> 25%

Reason:

> — Unless the two end crossings are different from the center crossing, it's not a knot.
>  — So there's a 50% × 50% = 25% chance that it *is* a knot.

Comment: ... and for completeness, if they _are_ both different then we have a standard knot.